# Formula for Formatting Date in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, visual-basic

I need to make a formula that will reformat a date in excel. My content is as below:

- Cell E4: 2/15/2012

I would like column E5 to be like this:

- Cell E5: 15 February 2012

Is there an easy way to do this? Thank you all!

Best,
Brandon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways you can do this:

In E5 use the formula

`=E4`

and then re-format E5 like this

Format Cells > Number > Custom and in the "Type" box paste this

`d mmmm yyyy`

or you can use this formula in E5

`=TEXT(E4,"d mmmm yyyy")`

The first one produces a formatted date - the second one (although it looks the same) produces a text string that looks like a date.

You don't really need an extra cell, though - you could simply apply the custom format to your original date in E4